# use callback with useState hook in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to update the user info on my database
on the **handleChange** function every time there is a new change but the problem that im facing is that i have to to wait for the setdata till it finish then updateUserInfo how i can solve that

```
  const [mydata, setData] = useState({
    user_gender: "",
    user_relationship: "",
    user_birth_day: "",
    user_birth_month: "",
    user_gender_interest: "",
    user_birth_year: "",
    user_interests: {
      dancing: false,
      family: false,
      art: false,
      photography: false,
      friends: false,
      travel: false
    }
  });

const handleChange = event => {
    setData({
      ...mydata,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    async function update() {
      await updateUserInfo(mydata[event.target.name], stableDispatch);
    }
    update();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Call updateUserInfo() as a callback.

You can pass a function as a 2nd parameter to setState() which will automatically be called when the state is set.

```
useEffect(() => {
  updateUserInfo(mydata[event.target.name], stableDispatch));
}, [mydata]);
```

Comment: "You can pass a function as a 2nd parameter to setState()" - this is only true for class-based components. The setter for the `useState` hook does not provide this after callback. Your use of the `useEffect` is correct though!

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer after I saw he was using hooks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to copy the state in a variable which you can use to update state and the userInfo

```
const handleChange = event => {

    const data = {
      ...mydata,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }
    setData(data);
    async function update() {
      await updateUserInfo(data[event.target.name], stableDispatch);
    }
    update();
  };
```